# Cups configuration does not consider my new PPD driver (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: debian, drivers, printing, cups

My Brother HL-4040CN is very unpredictible when trying to print images or PDFs. Searching around, I found an accurate driver description file at openprinting.org: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-HL-4040CN

I downloaded it to /usr/lib/cups/driver and, using cups admin console, I tried to change the driver of my printer. Unfortunately, even when deleting/recreating the printer, cups is putting back the default driver: Brother HL-4040CN Foomatic/pxlcolor (recommended) (color, 2-sided printing)

Do you have any suggestion to solve my printing issue ?